# Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "cordova-plugin-ionic". Please try adding it again

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Cannot install ionic plug in.

Step 1:

```
npm i cordova-plugin-ionic
```

Step 2:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic --save --variable APP_ID="myappid" --variable CHANNEL_NAME="Master" --variable UPDATE_METHOD="background"
```

Error:

> CordovaError: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "cordova-plugin-ionic". Please try adding it again.

Comment: I have the same issue, have you solved it already??