# Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "cordova-plugin-ionic"

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, ionic3

I have an ionic application and I want to add an android platform to it by using `ionic cordova platform add android` but it doesn't finish installing all of my plugins and stopped with **cordova-plugin-google-analytics** with this error.

[image: Cordova Error]

I even looked for solutions on the net but I didn't find some. I also noticed that there is already an existing topic the same with my problem but there is no solution so far.

[Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "cordova-plugin-ionic". Please try adding it again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255960/cannot-find-plugin-xml-for-plugin-cordova-plugin-ionic-please-try-adding-it-a)

Comment: Each plugin must have plugin.mxl file. If the file is missing you can either copy new plugin.xml from github repo or install the plugin again.

Comment: Make sure you removed/uninstalled previous plugin before installing again.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I just used the backup of my application files. Hehe